# Spring boot Security URL Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have set the root path as:-
server.contextPath=/myspringBootApp (in Application.propertes) file.

and changed the configuration file as:-

```
package com.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;


@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    MyDaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationTokenFilter();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider.authProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()

                // UI related urls
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/",
                        "/myspringBootApp/login",
                       "/content/**",
                        "/*.html",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js",
                        "/assets/**"
                ).permitAll()

                //Back end - auth layer
                .antMatchers("/auth/user").permitAll()

                //Back end - actual rest layer
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/auth/login").permitAll()

                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler);

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

}
```

The above code is not working and loading the UI. I tried changing the UI URLs to /myspringBootApp/favicon.ico, but this also dint give desired result.

Can anyone help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `WebSecurity` part of the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` for this:

```
@Override
public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/")
            .antMatchers("/favicon.ico")
            .antMatchers("/**.css")
            .antMatchers("/webjars/**")
            ...
```

Comment: Should I append /springbootApp to the above UI URLs?

Comment: I think you should not have any `server.contextPath` value in your configuration

Comment: No, it dint work.. The context path is getting picked up as per the logs:-org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/mySpringBootApp] - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
But this is neither applied to controllers and above security configuration. Why is it so?

Comment: Is it required to modify the rest URLs according to context-root?@maxb

Comment: the urls should be agnostic to the conextpath value, I'm not sure what exactly is not working for you